# Django models update multiple instance with foreign key objects in one transaction

Tags: django, django-models, sql-update, foreign-keys

In Django project I have three models:

```
class First(BaseModel):
   .....

class A(BaseModel):
   b = models.OneToOneField('B', null=True, blank=True, related_name='B%(class)s', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
   first = models.ForeignKey('First', related_name='a_list', on_delete=deletion.PROTECT)

class B(BaseModel):
   some_value = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=6, null=True, blank=True)
```

Inside one function, I would like to update the list of objects A with one transaction (so that I don't hit DB with multiple queries and updates).

I tried something like this:

```
first = First.objects.get(pk=id)
list_a = first.a_list.filter(...).select_related('b')

list_a.update(b__some_value=10)
```

The problem is that I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 608, in get_field
    return self.fields_map[field_name]
KeyError: 'b__some_value'

During the handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 2423, in ...
    resp = mview.post(self.get_url(), data=data, format='json')
  ....
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 610, in get_field
    raise FieldDoesNotExist("%s has no field named '%s'" % (self.object_name, field_name))
django.core.exceptions.FieldDoesNotExist: A has no field named 'b__some_value'
```

Does anyone know why I get this error or how to achieve the same results?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to update columns on related models with **update()** so there is no way to do in one transaction.
but instead you can filter based on related fields and then call **.update()**

something like this:

```
B.objects.filter(Ba__id__in=list_a).update(some_value=10)
```